# Get n largest key, value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
number = 2
dct = {'a': 5,'b': 3,'c': 4}

for key,value in dct.items():
```

I want to check the values that are the largest in the dictionary. The check depends on the number, so in this case, `{'a':5, 'c':4}` should be returned, since the number is `2`. However if the number was 1, only `{'a':5}` should be returned. I cannot import or use lambda

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without importing you can do it like this:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> mydict = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
>>> {key: mydict[key] for key in sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get, reverse=True)[:n]}
{'a': 5, 'c': 4}
```

The list comprehension is the equivalent of this:

```
result = {}
for key in sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get, reverse=True)[:n]:
    result.update({key: mydict[key]})
```

If multiple keys have the same value and you want to break the n largest rule then you need to use `set`.

```
>>> mydict = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}
>>> {key: value for key, value in mydict.items() if value in sorted(set(mydict.values()), reverse=True)[:2]}
{'a': 5, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}
```

You can also get the [`nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) and associated keys using a dict comprehension.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> n = 2
>>> mydict = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
>>> {key: value for key, value in mydict.items() if value in heapq.nlargest(n, mydict.values())}
{'a': 5, 'c': 4}
```

Comment: i like your way but i dont want it in one line

Comment: @CAVS happy now?:)

Comment: what if i have multiple keys with high values? mydict = {'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 4}, and the number is 2, i want to get {'a':5, 'c': 4, 'd':4}

Answer (score 1):

```
import heapq
number = 2
d={'a':5,'b':3,'c':4}
maximums = {k: d[k] for k in heapq.nlargest(number, d, key=lambda k: d[k])}
```

**UPDATE:** Without lambda and imports

```
number = 2
d={'a':5,'b':3,'c':4}
{i[1]:i[0] for i in sorted(zip(d.values(), d.keys()), reverse=True)[:number]}
```

Comment: i cannot import or use lambda

Answer (score 1):

See my answer

```
>>> number = 2
>>> dct = {'a': 5,'b': 3,'c': 4}
>>> lst = sorted([value for value in dct.values()],
                 reverse=True)[:number]
>>> result = {k: v for k, v in dct.items() if v in lst}
>>> result
{'a': 5, 'c': 4}
```

In `lst`, you will get a list of `dct` **values** in descending order which index is below `number`.

```
>>> lst
[5, 4]
```

Then `dct` is filtered which value is in `lst`.